# Android json parsing error (Froyo or less)

Tags: android, json

Ice Cream Sandwich, jelly beans will work just fine.
However, it should not work with earlier versions.

I do not know why. Give me some advice please.

jSon data :

```
{
 "ANDROID" :[
    {
        "NAME"  : "homepage",
        "URL"   : "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
        "IMAGE" : "http://www.stackoverflow/menu_01.png",
        "USE_YN"    : "Y",
        "APP_YN"    : "N"
    }
   ]        
}
```

error log :

```
org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

target source :

```
JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(jsondata);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 1):

```
 /*"ANDROID" :[
                {
                    "NAME"  : "homepage",
                    "URL"   : "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
                    "IMAGE" : "http://www.stackoverflow/menu_01.png",
                    "USE_YN"    : "Y",
                    "APP_YN"    : "N"
                }
               ]        
            }*/

            //here is the code to parse

            try {
                String jsondata = "your server response like above statements";

                if (jsondata != null && !jsondata.equals("")
                        && jsondata.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                    JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(jsondata);

                    if (jobject != null) {
                        if (jobject.has("ANDROID")) {
                            JSONArray jsonArr = jobject.getJSONArray("ANDROID");

                            if (jsonArr != null && jsonArr.length() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject json = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                                    if (json != null) {

                                        if (json.has("NAME")) {
                                            String name = json
                                                    .getString("NAME");
                                        }

                                        if (json.has("URL")) {
                                            String url = json.getString("URL");
                                        }

                                        if (json.has("IMAGE")) {
                                            String image = json
                                                    .getString("IMAGE");
                                        }

                                        if (json.has("USE_YN")) {
                                            String use = json
                                                    .getString("USE_YN");
                                        }

                                        if (json.has("APP_YN")) {
                                            String app = json
                                                    .getString("APP_YN");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```